# Recurrence relation similar to weighted Pascal's triangle

Tags: recurrence-relations

Consider $\mathbb C \langle x, y \rangle / \langle x y - \lambda y x - \mu \rangle$ for some constants $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb C$. I am trying to obtain a closed formula for $x^m y^n$, for general $m, n \in \mathbb N$, in terms of monomials of the form $y^k x^l$.

We have $x y^n = \lambda^n y^n x + \mu (1 + \lambda + \dotsb + \lambda^{n-1}) y^{n-1}$ and since $x^m y^n = x^{m-1} (x y^n)$ we thus get
$$
x^m y^n = x^{m-1} y^n x \lambda^n + x^{m-1} y^{n-1} \mu (1 + \lambda + \dotsb + \lambda^{n-1})
$$
which looks like a recurrence relation, but I don't know any techniques for writing down a closed formula of the form
$$
x^m y^n = \sum a_{kl} y^k x^l.
$$

It looks like the coefficients of $y^k x^l$ should be related to some kind of binomial coefficients for a "weighted" Pascal's triangle, where the usual Pascal's triangle has weights $1$ and the binomial coefficient is just counting the numbers of paths from the top.

Comment: This should be handy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient

Comment: another handy keyword is "quantum weyl algebras" ($\lambda=q$, $\mu=1$)

Comment: Which kind of underlying algebraic structure are you considering ? Not a simple **ring** ? Surely an **algebra** with $\lambda, \mu$ belonging to $\mathbb R$ or  $\mathbb C$ ? Could you give this precision ?

Comment: Possible connection with https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78813/binomial-expansion-for-non-commutative-setting and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172552

Comment: @JeanMarie I've edited the question to phrase this as a question about multiplication in some algebra. I don't immediately see how the linked questions cover the situation in my question, but I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @Quimey Quantum Weyl algebras seem indeed to be a useful keyword. I hope somebody has written the formula for the multiplication somewhere...

Comment: Another track: Pauli's Pascal triangle https://arxiv.org/ftp/physics/papers/0611/0611277.pdf